# Microsoft Teams Graph and OnlineMeetings

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've started to work on a proof of concept for a application that needs to create new Teams-meetings and provide a "Join Url". This URL can be distributed to external guests that might join the meeting as well.

After the meeting we would like to know how attended the meeting and ideally when the meeting ended etc.

What I've managed to do:

1. Create the meetings, get the OnlineMeeting-object back
2. Get meetings details based on the meeting.id this object does not contain any information about what happened in the meeting, only the things configured in 1. Example: If someone is configured as attended in step 1, they will show up but if a college just joins via the URL they will not show up.

What I need to do:

- Get a list of actual attendees
- Get information about the meetings length and actual start / end time.

I've played around with "Chat" which seems to be some kind of related thing, here it seems like I can get the attendees that joined the meeting but this does not display people that joined as a guest.

I've looked at the "Call" api as well and to be honest - I don't undestand the difference between a Call and a OnlineMeeting? But it seems like the only way to access the Call-API is with a Registered bot, the API throws an exception saying that my app is not registered in the store.

Comment: Currently There is no API that responds with the complete attendee list. Could you please check [this](https://www.jumpto365.com/blog/how-to-use-the-new-attendance-report-in-microsoft-teams-meetings#:~:text=Get%20the%20report%20during%20the,then%20click%20download%20attendance%20list.)? try if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Currently There is no API that responds with the complete attendee list. Could you please check [this](https://www.jumpto365.com/blog/how-to-use-the-new-attendance-report-in-microsoft-teams-meetings#:%7E:text=Get%20the%20report%20during%20the,then%20click%20download%20attendance%20list)